# Python - Create an array from columns in file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a text file with two columns and n rows. Usually I work with two separate vector using `x,y=np.loadtxt('data',usecols=(0,1),unpack=True)` but I would like to have them as an array of the form `array=[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]...]` where all the letters correspond to the x-vector and the numbers to the y-vector so I can ask something like `array[0,2]=b`. I tried defining
`array[0,:]=x` but I didn't succeed. Any simple way to do this?

In addition, I want to get the respective x-value for certain y-value. I tried with

```
x_value=np.argwhere(array[:,1]==3)
```

And I'm expecting the x_value to be c because it corresponds to 3 in column 1 but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to not unpack the array you get back from `loadtxt`. Do:

```
arr = np.loadtxt('data', usecols=(0,1))
```

If your file contained:

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
```

`arr` will be like:

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 5]]
```

Note that to index into this array, you need to specify the row first (and indexes start at 0):

```
arr[1,0] == 2 # True!
```

You can find the `x` values that correspond to a give `y` value with:

```
x_vals = arr[:,0][arr[:,1]==y_val]
```

The indexing will return an array, though `x_vals` will have only a single value if the `y_val` was unique. If you know in advance there will be only one match for the `y_val`, you could tack on `[0]` to the end of the indexing, so you get the first result.