# Python conversion from array to string column

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given two arrays, where

```
x=[1.2,2.2,3,4,5]
```

and

```
y=[10,8.999,6,4,1]
```

are combined to

```
data = [[1.2,2.2,3,4,5],[10,8.999,6,4,1]]
```

the output should match

```
data = '''
1.2    10
2.2    8.999
3    6
4    4
5    1
'''
```

I was thinking of saving to a file and reading again into the format I need, but was wondering if there is a more efficient way.  Similar to the opposite of [Python - Create an array from columns in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769007/python-create-an-array-from-columns-in-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe correct way will be something like this:

```
>>> print "\n".join(["%s     %s" % t for t in zip(x,y)])
1.2     10
2.2     8.999
3     6
4     4
5     1
>>>
```

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds :)

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick may be because I saw this question first, I voted you.

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick just one note, use format string instead `+` in your answer.

Comment: Ah yes, that would be better, +1 to you too!

Comment: Also, you might want to replace the multiple spaces with a `\t`; it is both pythonic, and it is pleasing to the eye as it lines up the second column :)

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick yes you are correct. and I think we can also use some tricks from [Python 2.7 quick reference](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/format-spec.html)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were thinking of?

```
string = "".join(["{}\t{}\n".format(str(x), str(y)) for x, y in zip(a, b)])
print string #Converts to pretty format
```

---

```
>>> a=[1.2,2.2,3,4,5]
>>> b=[10,8.999,6,4,1]
>>> string = "".join([str(x)+'\t'+str(y)+'\n' for x, y in zip(a, b)])
>>> print string
1.2 10
2.2 8.999
3   6
4   4
5   1

>>>
```

<sup>**Note: the `'\t'` shows up different on different consoles**</sup>

Comment: both work, but i gave the vote to the 2 seconds earlier, thanks :)

Comment: No prob, understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Both list into dictionary

```
x = [1.2,2.2,3,4,5]
y = [10,8.999,6,4,1]
dictionary = dict(zip(x, y))
print dictionary
```

Comment: why using `dict` when OP didn't say about dictonary?.

Answer (score 0):

`Zip` the `list` and then use formatting.

```
In [114]: for i in (zip(x, y)):
    print i[0],'\t',i[1]
   .....:     
1.2     10
2.2     8.999
3   6
4   4
5   1
```